# Style TreeviewItem layout (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, styles

I have a TreeView to which I bind a ObservableCollection where TreeView inherits TreeViewItem.

I want to style the header of the tree view to have a image in front of each header. I setted the header to the `ItemContainerStyle` but it did not chnage its layout. However it works for the `ContextMenu`.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
          <Setter Property="Header">
               <Setter.Value>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <Image Source="Images/Icons/Plus-48.png" Height="10" Width="10" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachinePartName}" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
               </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
          <Setter Property="ContextMenu">    
               <Setter.Value>
                     <ContextMenu>
                         <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddMachinePart_Command}"/>
                     </ContextMenu>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
     </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `HeaderTemplate` instead:

```
<Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding }" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images/Icons/Plus-48.png"
                               Height="10"
                               Width="10" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachinePartName}"
                                   Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Don't forget to bind `Header` property.

Comment: You are wellcome ))

Comment: However it seems that it doesn't bind for the children. Only the main tree nodes. The way I build the tree is adding TreeItem instances to the TreeItem.Items. Could this be the reason why it doesn t bind the rest of the nodes and only the first level nodes?

Comment: Check datacontext of children: do they have MachinePartName property? What are the values for MachinePartName?
Use snoop.

Comment: TreeItem.Items is of type ItemCollection ItemControl.

Comment: Do you use HierarchicalDataTemplate for your items template?

Comment: No, I add the children machine parts to the main node's Items list (ItemCollection ItemControl).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121842/discussion-between-mr-b-and-georgiana-m).

Comment: I think this is the reason why it doesn't work.
Your child item's data context should be instance of class that has property MachinePartName.